# Explicitly opening connection to IoT Hub from DeviceClient or opening it when a message is sent?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Are there any significant differences between explicitly opening a connection with `DeviceClient` at application initialisation or leaving it to open the connection itself when a message is sent?

What I mean by this is:

```
await deviceClient.OpenAsync(); // in main() etc.
...
await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Instead of just:

```
await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Are there any downsides to the latter? Is a connection held open regardless of how it's opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no advantage of calling DeviceClient.OpenAsync today. For all operations we internally make sure the device connection is opened.

Comment: What about the second part of the question: "Is a connection held open regardless of how it's opened?"

Comment: Yes - it is not being closed.